# logrotate is not working in RHEL7

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have enabled below log rotation on my VM but still logs are not getting rotated for next day, still I see logs are appending in 1 log file.

What I actually need is, imagine a service got started on April 7th and logs are writing, and the end of April 7th current log file should get zipped with April 7th and new log file should get created. But even after adding below entries in `logrotate.d` I still see logs are appending into the same log file.

Also if a log file reached 10MB then it should get rotated with `.gz` and new log file should get created. I could see log size crossed to 19MB but still no rotation happened.

Tried restarting `crond` services as well, still same issue. Please assist.

Below log file contains both April 7 & 8th entries

```
total 19140
-rw------- 1 aemelics aemelics 19M Apr  8 02:00 /logs/springboot/content-data-svc.log
```

**- Entries in logrotate.d**

```
cat /etc/logrotate.d/react

/logs/springboot/*.log

{

        copytruncate
        daily
        dateext
        rotate 3
        size 100M
        notifempty
        missingok
        compress
        postrotate
        endscript
  }
```

**Added entries in crontab as well**

```
crontab -l

45 * * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/react 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I believe if you use `size`, `logrotate` ignores `daily` and the other time based options.  I think the `logrotate` options you would need to accomplish your desired state are `maxsize` and `timeperiod`.

Comment: Thanks - if that is the case then i will reduce my requirement...I need a log file to get rotated daily with a time format and it should get zipped. Can you please share exact entries which i should add in /etc/logrotate.d ?

Comment: I think you ought to tell your service that the log was rotated. That is usually done by sending HUP signal. When a daemon receives that signal it should reread configuration, reopen log files, etc. If you do not do that, the daemon will keep the file pointer to the old file and will not write in the new log, that should have been created. If daemon does not support HUP signal, you have to restart it.

Comment: You should just need to remove the `size` line and it looks like your current `logrotate` would rotate daily and compress the result.  You probably do not need `postrotate` and `endscript` if you are not running a script after rotation.  You should also have the default `logrotate` cronjob at `/etc/cron.daily/logrotate`, if so you can remove your added `crontab` for `logrotate`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that restart should be done in `postrotate`.

Comment: Is crond running?

Comment: Crond is running. Created a test file under "test" directory with yesterday's date and executed logrotation command but not got rotated. Please advise

test]# ls -ltr
-rw------- 1 aemelics aemelics 0 Apr  7 00:00 content-data-svc.log

Comment: reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/react
Allocating hash table for state file, size 15360 B

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /lowes/logs/test/*.log
 after 1 days (no old logs will be kept)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
switching euid to 7002 and egid to 7003
considering log /lowes/logs/test/content-data-svc.log
  log does not need rotating (log has been already rotated)switching euid to 0 and egid to 0